# Strange colouring on faces

Tags: texturing

I have a model with strange colouring on some of the faces after I've sculpted. If I remove the faces and re-create them manually then they are fine and the colour appears as it should...the wierd faces are lighter in colour...

[image]

This is an image texture being applied to a UV map.

See also when next to the UV Editor these faces are missing...

[image]

Another EDIT:

Just found the faces, they were in the very bottom of the UV Editor...

[image]

If I do a Smart UV Project it fixes it, however then my texture image doesn't match the UV unwrap.

Just learning Blender so this might be a simple fix.

thanks

Dave

Comment: Try switching to **Edit Mode**, selecting your faces, pressing Alt+N and choosing _Recalculate Outside_. If not, try uploading the .blend file

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work but thanks for the suggestion. I've also tried to flip normals and do another UV unwrap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have checked them but you should see that the faces are properly attached, don't have any kind of vertex color / special properties in the vert data tab, and all have the same material.

Comment: Yeah when I move the faces the corresponding edges stay connected to the other faces on the object. I've just updated the original question to show that if I do a smart UV unwrap then it fixes my issue, but then causes another issue because the texture now doesn't line up with the new UV unwrap.

Comment: Sorry just bumping this.